# What is the most efficient way to store an image? HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, performance, image, optimization

I am going to have a lot of images and trying to find the most efficient way of storing these images to keep the page snappy.

So far I have thought of just the two ways: load with javascript eg `picture = new Image(); picture.src = "file.jpg";` and append / remove to the page as necessary, or load into `<img>` and set `display:none`.

Are there other options? what is considered the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for a photo gallery (if thats what you are building) is usually to have several sizes of the images, at least two:

1. a smallish size that is highly compressed and thus have a small footprint: this is the image you load into grids and display in a page where there are multiple images
2. a larger image with lower compression and higher image quality - this is the one you show when people want to see details.

Since people most often come to the detailed image from a page where the small/fast loading version has already been shown, and thus is already in the browsers cache, you do a little trick and have instant photos, without preloading anything.

It goes like this:

On the details page you show the highly compressed small image in an image tag that has the dimension of the larger detailed version. You then load the larger detailed version in the background using `new Image()` with an `onload` event attached that changes the source of the image tag with the small compressed version to the large detailed version.

It looks great, works fast and users will love you ;)

PS: the best way to store images is the browsers cache, not js or the DOM, so if you truly wish to preload images, which is generally a bad practice (tho it can be necessary sometimes), make the browser fetch them for you in the background by including a css file that references them in styles that aren't applied to visual areas of your site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about "efficient", but the most logical way would be not use the JavaScript to load an image (useless if you have JavaScript disabled) or to set the image as hidden via the display property (likewise, and the browser will probably just load the image anyway).

As such, a sensible suggestion would be to use boring old paging and display 'n' images per page. However, to bring this up to date, you could use "lazy" (a.k.a. "deferred") loading and load additional page content via Ajax as the user scrolls. However, it's key that this gracefully degrades into the standard "paged" behaviour if JavaScript is disabled, etc.

The perfect example of this in operation is Google's [image search](http://images.google.com/), and if you [search here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+lazy+loading+images) you see a discussion of possible implementations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use javascript the way that you have it and then add it to the DOM as you need, as opposed to first adding it to the to the DOM and then hiding it because DOM manipulation is much slower and you may not use some images